Implementing SignalR without Redis, and Without Sticky Sessions in Load Balance Environment
Currently working on a Net 8 Blazor project, and running into a hurdle in a load balanced environment. I don't currently have the ability to implement sticky sessions (or persistence) which is causing WebSocket errors in my application. Additionally using Redis is not going to be a good option.
Past this, I am already utilizing a custom distributed cache for other reasons, would it be possible to leverage the distributed cache as the backplane for SignalR in this scenario? If not, what are some other options or approaches I have to deal with the WebSocket errors here?

Please check the official suggestion link Third-party SignalR backplane providers first.

I have removed the  tag since this isn't really related to the ANSI/ISO SQL language. Perhaps you want to add a tag for the dbms you're using instead.
